# Changing one value of duplicate row in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a large(>2gb) dataset that need to be filtered for duplicates like this: if values in columns A,B,C,D and E are identical, then the value of E in every duplicate row (there can be multiple duplicates) has to be changed to 0.

Dataset:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e |
| a | b | c | d | e |
| a | b | c | d | e |

Output:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e |
| a | b | c | d | 0 |
| a | b | c | d | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need test duplicates in all columns use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with no parameter:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(), 'Column E'] = 0
print (df)
  Column A ColumnB Column C Column D Column E
0        a       b        c        d        e
1        a       b        c        d        0
2        a       b        c        d        0
```

If need test duplicates in columns from list `cols`:

```
cols = ['Column A', 'ColumnB', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E']
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=cols), 'Column E'] = 0
print (df)
  Column A ColumnB Column C Column D Column E
0        a       b        c        d        e
1        a       b        c        d        0
2        a       b        c        d        0
```